# Out results only if they = certain fields

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically I have a page that allows the user to post topics, the fields for that table are..

- topic_id
- category
- sub_category
- topic_data
- posted_by
- posted

I am trying to configure the page on the output page so that if the user posts to category "General" & sub_category "Stuff" it will then display all the records containing both the category name General & the Sub_cat of Stuff.

This is my code, it currently displays a blank white screen with no errors.

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id,
         topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
         topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
          FROM users, topics 
         WHERE topics.category = '" . $_GET['category'] . "' 
           AND topics.sub_category = '" . $_GET['sub_category'] . "'
      ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

using the above code if I go to `topics.php?category=General` it successfully displays the records for General, not sure if this is the correct way to do this though.

**EDIT**

Where the topic is posted I changed the header redirect from `topics.php` to `topics.php?category=$category&sub_category=$sub_category` which works, but I have 2 users on the system and it's now posting the same data as both users....

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this is for internal use only, no random hackers will have access to this site, thanks.

Comment: What difference does it make?  You've just made the second most common mistake when it comes to security.  Even if for some reason you don't care about security, you are still making broken queries by not escaping data.  Your application will inevitably fail.

Comment: Also, if you ever update your PHP to 5.5+ (which you should), you will find that all this work is pointless and will fail.  Be aware, just because this is not available on the Internet doesn't mean you should stop securing your code.  You could have a trojan or virus that targets Intranets.  Some stranger can come in and toy with someone's computer, etc.

Comment: The difference is right now I am getting the functionality to work before adding the security, no point painting the car when you don't know if it's going to be a sedan or wagon, the site is evolving so each day the way ti operates changes so I plan to do mysql injection security etc when I'm towards the end of the initial creation.

Comment: **No point painting a car if it won't run either unless you just like watching the decoration.**

Comment: @user2571547 You are bound to forget something and screw up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Location: topics.php?category=$category&sub_category=$sub_category
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I got that to work, just got another issue now, thanks for a post that actually addressed the issue.